# Duplicate current input fields and add extra row in table on the same page

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

Need to be able to add unlimited input fields if a user pressed a button "pievienot vel" also need  to add more table rows if a button is pressed. Sorry if the answer is somewhere, just couldn't find it. Currently I can only add one more input fields and one row in table bu pressing the buttons. 
Also new to PHP and html so don't judge my code :)

Any help is needed! :)

```
    <h3> Personīgā informācija </h3> 

<div id="Personal">

    <label>Vārds: </label>
    <input name="Name" type="text" size ="30"
     <?php
    if(isset($_POST['create'])) {
        echo "value='".$_POST['Name']."'";
    } else {
        echo "placeholder='Vārds'";
    }
    ?>  

    /> <br /><br />

    <label>Uzvārds: </label>
    <input name="Surname" type="text" size ="30" value="" placeholder='Uzvārds' /> <br /><br />

    <label>Dzimšanas gads: </label>
    <input name="DOB" type="text" size ="15" value="" placeholder="Dzimšanas Gads"  /> <br /><br />

    <label>E-pasts: </label>
    <input name="Email" type="text" size ="30" value="" placeholder="E-pasta adrese" /> <br /><br />

</div>

    <h3> Izglītības informācija 
    <button class="educationbtn" name="education" onclick="addText();" > Pievienot vel </button>
    </h3> 
<div id="Education" name="Educationdiv">

    <label>Iestādes nosaukums: </label>
    <input name="EdName[]" type="text" size ="30" value="" placeholder="Iestādes nosaukums" /> <br /><br />

    <label>Gads no - līdz: </label>
    <input name="Year1[]" type="text" size ="10" value="" placeholder="No" />
    <input name="Year2" type="text" size ="10" value="" placeholder="Līdz"  /> <br /><br />

    <label>Specialitāte: </label>
    <input name="Specialitate[]" type="text" size ="30" value="" placeholder="Specialitāte"  /> <br /><br />

</div>

    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['education']))
    { 
    ?>
    <label>Iestādes nosaukums: </label>
    <input name="EdName[]" type="text" size ="30" value="" placeholder="Iestādes nosaukums" /> <br /><br />

    <label>Gads no - līdz: </label>
    <input name="Year1[]" type="text" size ="10" value="" placeholder="No" />
    <input name="Year2" type="text" size ="10" value="" placeholder="Līdz"  /> <br /><br />

    <label>Specialitāte: </label>
    <input name="Specialitate[]" type="text" size ="30" value="" placeholder="Specialitāte"  /> <br /><br />

    <?php 

    }
    ?>
    <h3> Valodu zināšanu informācija 
    <button class="languagebtn" name="language"> Pievienot vel </button>
    </h3> 

<div id="Language">

    <table style="center" style="width:100%">

    <tr>
    <th> Valoda </th>
    <th> Runātprasme </th>
    <th> Lasītprasme </th>
    <th> Rakstītprasme </th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td> <input name="Lvtext" type="text" size ="10" value="Latviešu"  readonly /> </td></td>
    <td> <input name="LvRunat" type="text" size ="20" value=""  /> </td>
    <td> <input name="LvLasit" type="text" size ="20" value=""  /> </td>
    <td> <input name="LvRakstit" type="text" size ="20" value=""  /> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td> <input name="Engtext" type="text" size ="10" value="Angļu" readonly  /> </td></td>
    <td> <input name="EngRunat" type="text" size ="20" value=""  /> </td>
    <td> <input name="EngLasit" type="text" size ="20" value=""  /> </td>
    <td> <input name="EngRakstit" type="text" size ="20" value=""  /> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td> <input name="Rustext"type="text" size ="10" value="Krievu" readonly /> </td></td>
    <td> <input name="RusRunat" type="text" size ="20" value=""  /> </td>
    <td> <input name="RusLasit" type="text" size ="20" value=""  /> </td>
    <td> <input name="RusRakstit" type="text" size ="20" value=""  /> </td>
    </tr>

    <?php

        if(isset($_POST['language']))
        {
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td> <input name="Extext"type="text" size ="10" value=""  /> </td></td>
        <td> <input name="ExRunat" type="text" size ="20" value=""  /> </td>
        <td> <input name="ExLasit" type="text" size ="20" value=""  /> </td>
        <td> <input name="ExRakstit" type="text" size ="20" value=""  /> </td>
        </tr>
            <?php
        }
    ?>

    </table> 
    <br /><br />

</div>

<input type="submit" name="create" class="button" size="10" value="Create CV" />
<br /><br />
<br /><br />
```

Comment: where's the mysql?

Comment: You'll need javascript to add more input fields dynamically

Comment: So javascript would be the only way?

Comment: Pretty much. I suppose you *could* pass a variable into PHP and reload the page, but javascript is the "cleaner" way

Comment: Okay, thank you will look into javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
<script>
var count = 0;
function addNewInput(){

  var eDiv = document.getElementById('Education');
  var newInput = document.createElement('input');

  newInput.setAttribute('id', 'newInput'+ count);

  eDiv.appendChild(newInput);

  count++;

}
</script>
```

Then you can use the attribute onClick='addNewInput' in the button you want.

This is an example but I think this can give you an idea how you could do it in javascript for your form. Hope it can help you.